# Nginx Windows Laravel Routes not working

Tags: php, windows, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have installed nginx on my windows machine and i did a new installation of laravel. I created new routes but no other routes except the root work. I get a 404 error.

The error logs says

> "CreateFile() "C:\nginx/html/myproj/public/register" failed (2: The
>   system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server:
>   localhost, request: "GET /yacht/public/register HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "localhost""

Below is my nginx\conf\nginx.conf file.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}
```

Please suggest any ideas to solve this.

Comment: An explanation of what "_no other routes except the root seems to work_" means would be helpful. What did you do; what did you expect to happen; what actually happened that you didn't expect? These are the three things you must provide for us to be able to understand the problem.

Comment: edited my post. Pls check.

Comment: Unfortunately, "_it didn't work_" and "_I did unknown thing resulting in generic error_" aren't useful metrics to narrow down the potential list of things that may have gone wrong here. You need to check your nginx error logs and actually find more detailed error information about why the server is returning a 404 not found HTTP status code for a given URI. Otherwise, it's pointless to provide a list of the 1001 things that _could_ have possibly resulted in this generic error.

Comment: Please add your route file and the controller for the route that doesn't work.

Comment: Am not using a controller i am just returning a view in that route.

Comment: @RamChandran Were you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

problem could be because of the slash and backslashes of

```
C:\nginx/html/myproj/public/register
```

I think it is better to use

```
php artisan serve
```

in local instead of using nginx .

Comment: Hey many thanks. This worked!! Is there any way to configure nginx to avoid this.

Comment: I think you should edit nginx configuration file to correct this .

Answer (score 1):

In your nginx configuration, root should point to the Laravel public folder. i.e.

```
 server {
    listen   80 default_server;

    root /var/www/laravel/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Comment: he's using windows